# why does array.shift skip a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function

```
$(this).each(function(index) {

            arr[index] = ($(this).attr('id'));
            console.log(arr[index]);            

            fullId[index] = "#"+arr.shift();
            console.log(fullId[index]);     
});
```

The results I'm expecting are

```
A
#A
B
#B
C
#C
D
#D
```

The actual results are

```
A
#A
B
Undefined
C
#B
D
Undefined
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You realize that `shift`ing `arr` changes the indexes of all items in the array, right?

And yet won't affect `$(this)` at all?

Comment: I don't understand your answer/question?

Comment: Try printing the entirety of `arr` after each call to `shift`. It'll make the problem clear.